# Inserting modified pixel data in a multiframe dicom image?

Tags: c++, image, dicom

First I should mention that I'm using the Dcmtk library for this purpose.

I've already managed to learn how I can modify the pixel data of a single frame dicom image. Now,I'm trying to do the same in case of multiframe images. I'm can extract all the necessary information and even can extract the pixel data individually for each frame and can modify them. But the problem arise when I have to insert the modified pixel data. In case of single frame I use the method in DcmDataset:

```
putAndInsertUint8Array()
```

But I can't see any option like that for the multi-frame image. I get the pixel data for each frame using this method in DcmElement:

```
getUncompressedFrame()
```

where I just have to put the frame index to get the corresponding pixel data. But while inserting I could not find any such option. My programming code is as following:

```
int main()
{
   MdfDatasetManager file;
   if(EC_Normal==file.loadFile("test.dcm",ERM_autoDetect,EXS_Unknown))
   {
      DcmDataset *dataset = file.getDataset();
      E_TransferSyntax xfer= dataset->getOriginalXfer();
      bool OriginallyCompressed=false;
      if(xfer!=0 && xfer !=1 && xfer!=2 && xfer!=3)
      {
         OriginallyCompressed=true;
         DJDecoderRegistration::registerCodecs();
         if(EC_Normal==dataset->chooseRepresentation(EXS_LittleEndianExplicit, NULL))
         {
            if(dataset->canWriteXfer(EXS_LittleEndianExplicit))
            {
               cout<<"Originally it's a compressed image, but now decompressed!\n";
            }
         }
      }
      DcmElement* element=NULL;
      Uint16 rows = 0;
      Uint16 cols = 0;
      Uint16 samplePerPixel = 0;
      Uint16 planarConfiguration = 0;
      int index=0;
      // I've fixed these values but later I will change them to dinaymic and make it work as per user's wish.
      int ymin=50;//minimum rows
      int ymax=500;//maximum rows
      int xmin=100;//Minimum columns
      int xmax=600;//Maximum columns
      if(EC_Normal==dataset->findAndGetUint16(DCM_Rows, rows))
      {
         if(EC_Normal==dataset->findAndGetUint16(DCM_Columns, cols))
         {
            if(EC_Normal==dataset->findAndGetUint16(DCM_SamplesPerPixel,samplePerPixel))
            {   
               if(EC_Normal==dataset->findAndGetUint16(DCM_PlanarConfiguration,planarConfiguration))
               {
                  if(EC_Normal==dataset->findAndGetElement(DCM_PixelData,element))
                  {
                     Uint32 startFragment=0;
                     Uint32 sizeF=0;
                     element->getUncompressedFrameSize(dataset,sizeF);
                     long int numOfFrames=0;
                     dataset->findAndGetLongInt(DCM_NumberOfFrames,numOfFrames);
                     for(int i=0;i<int(numOfFrames);i++)
                     {
                        Uint8 * buffer = new Uint8[int(sizeF)];
                        OFString decompressedColorModel=NULL;
                        DcmFileCache * cache=NULL;
                        if(EC_Normal==element->getUncompressedFrame(dataset,i,startFragment,buffer,sizeF,decompressedColorModel,cache))
                        {
                           Uint8 * newBuffer = new Uint8[int(sizeF)];
                           if(buffer != NULL)
                           {
                              for(unsigned long y = 0; y < rows; y++)
                              {
                                 for(unsigned long x = 0; x < cols; x++)
                                 {
                                    if(planarConfiguration==0)
                                    {
                                       if(x>xmin && x<xmax && y>ymin && y<ymax)
                                       {
                                          index=(x + y +  y*(cols-1))*samplePerPixel;
                                          newBuffer[index]  = 0;
                                          newBuffer[index + 1]  = 0;
                                          newBuffer[index +2]  = 0;
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                          index=(x + y +  y*(cols-1))*samplePerPixel;
                                          newBuffer[index]  = buffer[index];
                                          newBuffer[index + 1]  = buffer[index + 1];
                                          newBuffer[index + 2]  = buffer[index + 2];
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                           delete newBuffer;
                        }
                        delete buffer;
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I just manage to find a way to insert the modified pixel data for each frame, this program will be complete. Please suggest me what I should do. Or please say me, if you know, how the whole pixel data of all the frames in a multiframe dicom image is stored together. Then maybe I can take the whole pixel data together from all the frames and modify them and then try to insert the whole modified pixel data together.

Answer (score 0):

case#1, uncompressed pixel data:

```
///. get PixelData element in DCM dataset
pDcmDataSet->findAndGetPixelData(...);
///. get pixels in PixelData element
pDcmPixelDataSet->findAndGetOW(...);
```

You will get the whole pixel data of all the frames in one piece.

case#2, compressed pixel data:

```
///. get PixelData element in DCM dataset
pDcmDataSet->findAndGetPixelData(...);
///. get PixelSequence in PixelData element
pPixelData->getEncapsulatedRepresentation(...)
///. get PixelItem in PixelSequence
pDcmPixelSequence->getItem(...);
///. get frame in Pixel Item
pPixelItem->getUint8Arrary(...);
```

You will get one frame of a compressed image.